# Return Rows that Can be Multiple Types

Tags: sql-server

Ok, I've been searching for two days and have not found anything.   I think this is a simple problem, I'm just not able to wrap my head around it for some reason.

Say you have two tables.

**Cars**

```
CarID
CarModel
```

**CarTypes**

```
CarTypeID
CarID
TypeOfCar
```

Example data for `Cars`:

```
CarID CarModel
A      Pinto 
B      Corvette
C      Ferrari
```

Example data for `CarTypes`:

```
CarTypeID CarID TypeOfCar
1           A    ChickMagnet
2           A    FourDoor
3           A    GasGuzzler

4           B    SportsCar
5           B    TwoDoor
6           B    GasGuzzler

7           C    GasGuzzler
8           C    TwoDoor
9           C    ChickMagnet
```

Car and CarType have a 1 to many relationship (A car can be many different types).   I cannot wrap my head around the sql that would be required to show all cars that are a "ChickMagnet" AND a "GAS Guzzler"

Result Set Desired:

```
CarID CarModel
A     Pinto
C     Ferrari
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm using SQL Server. I can do it using Like and Text searches but would like to avoid that.

Comment: you need to make a join with the two tables and use a where clause to select which Types of Car you want to select

Comment: Is it ok to have duplicated CarTypeIDs? There are twice of 3 and 7.

Comment: @TrueSoft, Edited to correct CarTypeIDs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT c.CarID, c.CarModel
FROM Cars c
INNER JOIN CarTypes ct
ON c.CarID = ct.CarID
WHERE ct.TypeOfCar IN ('ChickMagnet', 'GasGuzzler')
GROUP BY c.CarID, c.CarModel
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ct.TypeOfCar) = 2
```

Comment: I learned something new with this (Group By will work if the aggregate is in the Having Clause).   Performance wise,  which is worse:  the sorting required by Group By or multiple inner joins? In reality, the Group By will be done on about 15 different columns.  Either this answer or @Oded works (thanks!) just looking for the most scalable of the two.  Amount of data is in the 10's of thousands of rows.

Comment: Read more: [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/)

Comment: @MizardX - Thanks for the link, that answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way:

```
SELECT c.CarId, c.CarModel
FROM Cars c
  INNER JOIN CarTypes ct1 
     ON c.CarID = ct1.CarID
  INNER JOIN CarTypes ct2
     ON c.CarID = ct2.CarID
WHERE ct1.TypeOfCar = 'ChickMagnet'
  AND ct2.TypeOfCar = 'GasGuzzler'
```

Comment: Awesome. This makes sense to me.   Will this scale decently if I continue to blow out the inner joins?    Say I want cars that match 100 types.... more out of interest than really a need (the most I'll need is 4)

Comment: @OpenR - Joins are expensive, so not very scalable. If you have a small amount of data, this should be OK though.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but as long as Stuart's formulation works it's quite a bit more scalable as you get to more and more types.  For this limited dataset it's a wash, though.

Answer (score 0):

Just off the top of my head, couldn't you use where CarID in() and CarID in ()